# Want to crawl a post using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

Click the link on the list page (random)
After seeing the content for 3 seconds
I want to repeat another random click.

View the content of a post, not the purpose of collection, and return to the list to see the content of another post ...

It is such a repetitive task.

The code below works, but I can't seem to random click on the list

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('/test')

list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="re_href"]')

list_of_linktext = []

for link in list_of_links:
    list_of_linktext.append(link.text)


for linktext in list_of_linktext:
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(linktext)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    sleep(3)
    driver.back()
    sleep(3)
```

html

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="num">512</td>
            <td class="thumb"><img src="test.jpg"></td>
            <td class="subject">
                <a href="/article/band/13538" id="re_href" class="re_href">Title</a>
            </td>
            <td class="writer"></td>
            <td class="check"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="num">512</td>
            <td class="thumb"><img src="test2.jpg"></td>
            <td class="subject">
                <a href="/article/band/14230" id="re_href" class="re_href">Title</a>
            </td>
            <td class="writer"></td>
            <td class="check"></td>
        </tr>
.
.
.
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Its not clicking because I think this selector : element = driver.find_element_by_link_text(linktext)
depends more than one element.

Comment: @SelçukAyhan thank you.But I did not understand well.

Comment: If there are two elements with link text `Title` this code is not gonna work.

Comment: @SelçukAyhan So this code is just one link working. Can you make multiple links work? Even a hint ...

Comment: @soria : what does it means random click? would you like to click each link one by one?

Comment: @KunduK Yes. That's right.I want to loop through a click once for each link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code it will click each link.

```
driver.get('/test')

list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="re_href"]')

for linktext in range(len(list_of_links)):
    list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="re_href"]')

    element =list_of_links[linktext]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    sleep(3)
    driver.back()
    sleep(3)
```

---

**Edited:**

Use the below xpath for all the links inside table.

```
driver.get('/testl')

list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject']/a")

for linktext in range(len(list_of_links)):
    list_of_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//tr//td[@class='subject']/a")

    element =list_of_links[linktext]
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
    sleep(3)
    driver.back()
    sleep(3)
```

Comment: Thank you very much.I noticed that they are being clicked sequentially.Thank you again.

Comment: I'll ask you one more question.Can you continue the whole process?

Comment: @soria : `Can you continue the whole process` not getting your question?

Comment: Currently, only the number of "class =" re_href "is executed.Can't I keep my code running?

Comment: The html you have posted you have `class="re_href"` right.If you have other classname links present you need to post that as well.

Comment: what you could do use below xpath : `//table//tr//td[@class='subject']/a`